# Length of covering $2D$ Grid circles

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

Covering the 2D grid $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with concentric circles, what is the sequence of length of radii?

Comment: For centers with integral coordinates, the answer is [straightforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem). If your point of interest is rational (or maybe quadratic-irrational, or whatever else) coordinates of the center, you should probably state it explicitly...

Comment: Thanks metamorphy, the link answers my question--with a small reservation: I guess there is no nice explicit analytic expression for this sequence of numbers?